# Exercise in Applied Mathematics Logan's Book (functional)

Tags: calculus

From David Logan book (Applied Mathematics) page 175.

Show that Euler Equation for the functional 
 $$J(y)=\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\sqrt{1+(y')^2)} dx$$
has the form 
$$f_y-f_xy'-f\frac{y''}{1+(y')^2}=0$$

I have found that:
$$L_y(x,y,y')=f_y\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$$
$$L_{y'}(x,y,y')=f(x,y)\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}$$
$$\frac{dL_{y'}(x,y,y')}{dx}=f_{x}(x,y)\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}+f(x,y)\frac{y''}{(1+(y')^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

and finally (by Euler Equation) i have found:
$$f_y(1+(y')^2)-f_xy'-f\frac{y''}{1+(y')^2}=0$$

What wrong with that?

Comment: I think you missed out the third term in the detivative of  $L_{y'}$.

Comment: oh my goddddd thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Applying the first variation we get

$$
\frac{\left(y'(x)^2+1\right) \left(f_y(x,y(x))-y'(x) f_x(x,y(x))\right)-y''(x) f(x,y(x))}{\left(y'(x)^2+1\right)^{3/2}}=0
$$

or

$$
\left(y'(x)^2+1\right) \left(f_y(x,y(x))-y'(x) f_x(x,y(x))\right)-y''(x) f(x,y(x)) = 0
$$

or

$$
f_y(x,y(x))-y'(x) f_x(x,y(x))-\frac{y''(x) f(x,y(x))}{y'(x)^2+1} = 0
$$